# How do I solve using the line equation through (2,3) and (4,1)?

Tags: geometry

My teacher just taught me Coordinate Geometry and she is very fast :3 I cant really cope with the phase and i got loads of homework now.

One of the question is "Find the equation of the straight line which passes through the point (2,3) and (4,1)"

the equation of straight line is $y = mx + c$ right? and what are we suppose to find? is it the c?

and is the final answer gonna be like $y =$ number(x) + number ? or what only $c$

thank you

Comment: 3+ answers all basically identical in 3,2,1...

Comment: @Zach466920 haha this, but at least I can say I was first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose you want an equation in slope-intercept form. Thus, you obviously need two things: the slope, and the y-intercept. To get the slope $m$, you can use the formula $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}.$$ On the line you are given two points $(x_1,y_1)=(2,3)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(4,1)$. Thus, plugging into the above formula $$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{1-3}{4-2}=-1.$$ Thus the slope of the line is $-1$.

Now you have an equation in *point-slope form*. You know one point of the line (in fact, two but you can choose either) and the slope. This is one form, and you can use it to write the equation $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$ where $(x_1,y_1)$ is a point of the line (say $(2,3)$). You can then plug in to get one possible equation of your line, and solving for $y$ yields the slope-intercept form $y=mx+b$.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute the values of the points in the equation $y=mx+c$ to get this nice system: 
\begin{cases} 3=2m+c \\ 1=4m+c \end{cases}
Then solve it for $m$ and $c$ to get $m=-1$ and $c=5$.

Then the equation of the line you search is given by $y=-x+5$